# Android how can i get thumb image of video file from gallery

Tags: android, video, uri, thumbnails, android-gallery

I need to show the selected video file from gallery in my listview. 
I have successfully fetched the uri of video file but i am not able to get the thumb image of video file. Here is the code i have used for fetching image of video file from uri, but is causes the app to crash. Is there any other way to get image of video file..? please assist me if it can be achieved in any other way....

```
public static String getFileMetaData(Context context,String uri){
        Uri queryUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        // Get relevant columns for use later.
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE
        };
// Return only video and image metadata.
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                queryUri,
                projection,
                selection,
                null, // Selection args (none).
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" // Sort order.
        );

        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA);

        Log.d("MyTag","***************** : " + cursor.getString(columnIndex));

        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this problem with some changes. Actually my problem was the file path that i had given is wrong.I have been giving the Uri got from gallery, 
    now i had changed the code for getting the real path from Uri and 
    then applied them to ThumbnailUtils for creating thumb image.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri);
String mUri = AppUtils.getRealPathFromURI(mActivity,uri,"VIDEO");
mImageSend.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                            mUri, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND));


public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context,Uri contentURI,String type) {

        String result  = null;
        try {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                result = contentURI.getPath();
                Log.d("TAG", "result******************" + result);
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = 0;
                if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("IMAGE")){
                    idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("VIDEO")){
                    idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
                }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("AUDIO")){
                    idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA);
                }
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
                Log.d("TAG", "result*************else*****" + result);
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception ",e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the video file uri first you have to get filepath of video file then from filepath you can generate video thumb.

You can get thumbnail using **createVideoThumbnail** method of **ThumbnailUtils** class like this.

```
video_imageview.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideoFilePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND));
```

In which selectedVideoFilePath is video file path. You can get file path using this.

```
String selectedVideoFilePath = GetFilePathFromDevice.getPath(this, videoFileUri);
```

You can use **GetFilePathFromDevice** class to get filepath from given Uri.

GetFilePathFromDevice.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public final class GetFilePathFromDevice {

    /**
     * Get file path from URI
     *
     * @param context context of Activity
     * @param uri     uri of file
     * @return path of given URI
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!