# How to get thumb image of picked video from gallery?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, imageview

I picked a video from gallery. But i want to show this selected video's thumb image to imageview.
 **What i did**

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                thumbVideoImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);


              String  filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

              thumbVideoImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                // MEDIA GALLERY
                selectedVideoPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedVideoPath != null) {



                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but nothing happened. Any advice or sample code please ? 
**And one other question is**  which url of video should i use to post it to server ? thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044061/android-how-can-i-get-thumb-image-of-video-file-from-gallery see this

Comment: I tried this code :
video_imageview.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideoFilePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND));
But nothing happened again

Answer (score 0):

When you pick image from gallery you should convert to bitmap and resize bitmap to smaller -> this bitmap is thubmnail, at the same time you save url from variable to get original image when needed.